# Removing any existing file from Dropzone shows dictDefaultMessage

Tags: php, dropzone.js

I've created a dropzone showing existing files on the server. I've added remove links which work. My problem is that when I remove a file with its remove link, the default "Drop files here to upload" message appears in the dropzone even though there are still thumbnails remaining.

I've followed this [tutorial](http://www.startutorial.com/articles/view/dropzonejs-php-how-to-display-existing-files-on-server) and updated with

```
myDropzone.emit("addedfile", mockFile);

// And optionally show the thumbnail of the file:
myDropzone.emit("thumbnail", mockFile, "/image/url");

// Make sure that there is no progress bar, etc...
myDropzone.emit("complete", mockFile);
```

from Enyo's FAQ.

Why would this be happening?

On a dropzone with no existing files, this message only appears when the last file is removed.

All help appreciated.

Cheers,

Tane

Answer (score 4):

Ok I've figured it out, no need to add code to manually change class names. Just add this when you're adding your mockfiles.

```
mydropzone.files.push(mockFile);
```

This files array is what dropzone is using to determine if the dropzone is empty or not. And when I was just changing the length property, code was crashing trying to access an array that was never filled.

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you provide some working code, for example on jsfiddle.net, to have better understanding what are you trying to describe here.

If I got it right, you need to catch event that there are no files to show, which is whenever you `data` variable is empty in `init` function on javascript side when the dropzone is loaded.

Also this should be handled in events `thumbnail` or `addedfile` and with `removedfile`. Here you can count how many files are currently available.