# Dropzone.js when removing a mock file created on page load, the default add files message shows

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

There is a previous unanswered question about this here but no code or answer was provided. I'm hoping providing some code you'll be able to help me out.

[Removing any existing file from Dropzone shows dictDefaultMessage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30274061/removing-any-existing-file-from-dropzone-shows-dictdefaultmessage/34904318#34904318)

When I load the page I'm adding mock files to the dropzone. When I click remove on one of those files, the default add image text displays in the dropzone even though there are still files present. How does dropzone keep track of the number of files in the drop zone. I've tried directly modifying the myDropzone.files.length property to match the number of mock files but it breaks the dropzone as I've said in the other question. Here is my code for dropzone.

```
var jsphotos = '@jsphotos';

var mockFiles = [];


Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
var fileList = new Array;
var fileListCounter = 0;


var photoDropzone = new Dropzone('#photoDropzone', {
    url: 'importphotos.cshtml',
    paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
    maxFilesize: 5, // MB
    method: 'post',
    acceptedFiles: 'image/jpeg,image/pjpeg',
    dictInvalidFileType: 'Files uploaded must be type .jpg or .jpeg',

    init: function () {
        this.on("addedfile", function (file) {

            // remove size
            file.previewElement.querySelector('.dz-size').innerHTML = '';

             // add custom button
             // Create the remove button
             var removeButton = Dropzone.createElement('<i class="fa fa-times-circle-o fa-3x removeButton"></i>');

             // Capture the Dropzone instance as closure.
             var _this = this;

             // Listen to the click event
             removeButton.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
                 // Make sure the button click doesn't submit the form:
                 e.preventDefault();
                 e.stopPropagation();

                 // Remove the file preview.
                 _this.removeFile(file);

            });

            // Add the button to the file preview element.

            file.previewElement.appendChild(removeButton);
        });

        this.on("success", function (file, serverFileName) {
            file.previewElement.querySelector('.dz-filename').innerHTML = '<span data-dz-name>'+serverFileName+'</span>';
        });


        this.on("removedfile", function (file) {

            //var rmvFile = "";
            //for (f = 0; f < fileList.length; f++) {

            //    if (fileList[f].fileName == file.name) {
            //        rmvFile = fileList[f].serverFileName;
            //        fileListCounter--;
            //    }

            //}

            //if (rmvFile) {
            //    $.ajax({
            //        url: "deletephoto.cshtml",
            //        type: "POST",
            //        data: { "fileList": rmvFile }
            //    });
            //}
        });

    }


});


$('#photoDropzone').sortable({
    items: '.dz-preview',
    cursor: 'move',
    opacity: 0.5,
    containment: "parent",
    distance: 10,
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    sort: function (event, ui) {
        var $target = $(event.target);
        if (!/html|body/i.test($target.offsetParent()[0].tagName)) {
            var top = event.pageY - $target.offsetParent().offset().top - (ui.helper.outerHeight(true) / 2);
                ui.helper.css({ 'top': top + 'px' });
        }
    },
    update: function (e, ui) {
        // do what you want
    }
});


if (jsphotos.length > 0) {
    var tmpSplit = jsphotos.split(',');

    for (i = 0; i < tmpSplit.length; i++) {
        if (tmpSplit[i].length > 0) {
            mockFiles.push(tmpSplit[i]);
        }
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < mockFiles.length; i++) {
    // Create the mock file:
    var mockFile = { name: mockFiles[i]};

    // Call the default addedfile event handler
    photoDropzone.emit("addedfile", mockFile);
    photoDropzone.emit("success", mockFile, mockFile.name);

    // And optionally show the thumbnail of the file:
    //photoDropzone.emit("thumbnail", mockFile, '@Globals.tempUploadFolderURL'  + mockFile.name);
    // Or if the file on your server is not yet in the right
    // size, you can let Dropzone download and resize it
    // callback and crossOrigin are optional.
    photoDropzone.createThumbnailFromUrl(mockFile, '@Globals.tempUploadFolderURL' + mockFile.name);

    // Make sure that there is no progress bar, etc...
    photoDropzone.emit("complete", mockFile);

    // If you use the maxFiles option, make sure you adjust it to the
    // correct amount:
    //var existingFileCount = 1; // The number of files already uploaded

    //Dropzone.options.maxFiles = myDropzone.options.maxFiles - existingFileCount;
}

//photoDropzone.files.length = mockFiles.length;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After attempting to code a solution that monitored the count manually and modified the value of the default text, I didn't want a hack to modify class names to 'fool' the dropzone into thinking there were files. So I added this

```
photoDropzone.files.push(mockFile);
```

just below

```
photoDropzone.emit("complete", mockFile);
```

and now dropzone knows how many files it has, and everything functions appropriately. Files pushed into the array do not get resubmitted, it's the same as adding the mock preview originally.